# eclipse JVMMonitor does not show anything even when successfully start monitoring

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I recently installed JVM monitor to Eclipse Luna. Although the monitoring seems successfully started, nothing is shown in 'property' view. How can I see the result of monitoring?

My environment is here

- Eclipse Luna Service Release 2 (4.4.2)
- JVM monitor 3.8.1
- OS: ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS

[image]
[image]

**Updata**

Eclipse's log is here:

```
!ENTRY org.eclipse.ui 

    4 0 2015-05-22 08:29:18.691
    !MESSAGE Unhandled event loop exception
    !STACK 0
    org.eclipse.swt.SWTException: Failed to execute runnable (java.lang.NullPointerException)
              at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4441)
              at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4356)
              at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Synchronizer.runAsyncMessages(Synchronizer.java:139)
              at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runAsyncMessages(Display.java:3774)
              at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3412)
              at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$9.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1151)
              at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
              at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1032)
              at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:148)
              at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Workbench.java:636)
              at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
              at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:579)
              at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:150)
              at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:135)
              at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
              at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:134)
              at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
              at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:380)
              at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:235)
              at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
              at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
              at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
              at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:648)
              at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:603)
              at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1465)
              at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1438)
      Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
              at org.jvmmonitor.internal.ui.views.StartMonitoringAction.openPropertiesView(StartMonitoringAction.java:265)
              at org.jvmmonitor.internal.ui.views.StartMonitoringAction.showPropertiesView(StartMonitoringAction.java:151)
              at org.jvmmonitor.internal.ui.views.StartMonitoringAction$1$1.run(StartMonitoringAction.java:103)
              at org.eclipse.ui.internal.UILockListener.doPendingWork(UILockListener.java:167)
              at org.eclipse.ui.internal.UISynchronizer$3.run(UISynchronizer.java:165)
              at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.RunnableLock.run(RunnableLock.java:35)
              at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Synchronizer.runAsyncMessages(Synchronizer.java:136)
              ... 24 more
```

Comment: Altough `luna` is not officially supported, it runs on it for most users... have you check your log in `workspace_location/.metadata/.log ` ?

Comment: @flafoux Thank you. I did not know the log location of eclipse. I updated the question to add the error log.